# JavaScript/Canvas появление объекта через заданное время

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, canvas

Подскажите, как реализовать появление объекта (красного квадрата) через setTimeout()

Я реализовал по-другому, но почему-то кажется, что так не правильно, или такое решение имеет место быть?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("d1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var pressedLeft = false;
var pressedRight = false;
var pressedUp = false;
var pressedBottom = false;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp, false);

function keyDown(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 37) {
  pressedLeft = true;
   }
   else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
    pressedRight = true;
   }
   else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
    pressedUp = true;
   }
   else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
    pressedBottom = true;
   }
}

function keyUp(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 37) {
    pressedLeft = false;
   }
   else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
    pressedRight = false;
   }
   else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
    pressedUp = false;
   }
   else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
    pressedBottom = false;
   }
}

var player = {
 x: 10,
   y: 10,
   pW: 130,
   pH: 130,
   draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.pW, this.pH);
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
   }
}

var box = {
 x: 5,
   y: 5,
   bW: 140,
   bH: 140,
   timer: 0,
   draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.bW, this.bH);
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
   }
}

function draw() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
   box.timer++;
   if(box.timer >= 150) {
    box.draw();
   }
  
   player.draw();
  
   if(pressedRight) {
    player.x = 162;
   }
   if(pressedLeft) {
    player.x = 10;
   }
   if(pressedUp) {
    player.y = 10;
   }
   if (pressedBottom) {
    player.y = 162;
   }
}

setInterval(draw, 1000/60);
```

```css
#d1 {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: #fff url('http://jscoder.ru/bg1.jpg');
}
```

```html
<canvas id="d1" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем Вам постоянно перерисовывать квадрат, а не делать это в обработчиках событий клавиатуры.

Comment: Если не сложно, можно маленький примерчик, чтобы квадрат хотя бы влево вправо двигался.

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем понятно, зачем Вам постоянно перерисовывать квадрат, а не делать это в обработчикe события:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("d1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp, false);

function keyUp(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    player.x = 10;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    player.x = 162;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    player.y = 10;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    player.y = 162;
  }
  draw();
}

var player = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  pW: 130,
  pH: 130,
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.pW, this.pH);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

var box = {
  x: 5,
  y: 5,
  bW: 140,
  bH: 140,
  timer: 0,
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.bW, this.bH);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  box.draw();
  player.draw();
}
draw();
```

```css
#d1 {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: #fff url('http://jscoder.ru/bg1.jpg');
}
```

```html
<canvas id="d1" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```